# converting xcopy to robocopy

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

Tried to use xcopy and excluding a folder and all its subfolders.

```
C:\Merged\org\a>xcopy /I /E /Y C:\Merged\org\*.* C:\Merged\dest /exclude:"C:\Mer
ged\org\a\*.*"
Can't read file: "C:\Merged\org\a\*.*"
```

I guess I cannot exclude folder, but only file with xcopy.

So I think of moving to robocopy, but I'm not sure which flags to use.

What is the equivalent robocopy to my above xcopy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can. Read up on `XCOPY /?`:

> /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
>                  Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
>                  should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
>                  strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
>                  copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
>                  example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
>                  all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
>                  .obj extension respectively.

The problem is you specify the path you want to exclude to `/EXCLUDE` when you should specify the name of a file, which contains the "paths" to exclude (it is actually more flexible see above). The error message you get even hints at that.

Create a file, e.g. `C:\ignore.txt`, that contains the line "C:\Merged\orga\a\", then invoke `XCOPY` as follows:

```
xcopy.exe C:\Merged\org\*.* C:\Merged\dest /exclude:C:\ignore.txt /I /E /Y
```

If you want to use robocopy nevertheless, you can do so like:

```
robocopy.exe c:\merged\org c:\merged\dest /xd c:\merged\org\a /IS /E
```

Comment: I couldn't find equivalent to /I /Y flags. Does your robocopy includes them?

Comment: /I is implied. Instead of /Y use /IS to overwrite existing files (otherwise robocopy will ignored unchanged, existing files at the destination).

Answer (score 0):

I has been wrote seemless wrappers from `xcopy` command line to the `robocopy`. You can find it from here: https://github.com/andry81/contools.

The scripts:

https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/std/xcopy_dir.bat
https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/std/xcopy_file.bat